# Where did Apple's JRE 1.6 store applet runtime parameters?

Tags: macos, applet, java, jnlp

We needed to roll back from Oracle's JRE 1.7 to Apple's JRE 1.6 because of the copy/paste regression. We followed these instructions from apple:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559

That mostly worked, except our Java Preferences panel was gone. So we restored that from Time Machine. That mostly works (for example, changing whether the console pops open works), however, it refuses to save changes to applet runtime parameters (e.g., -Xmx1024M). There is no error, but the applet doesn't see what we put in, and if we re-start the Preferences utility, the values we set are gone.

I'll happily go edit some text file, but I cannot figure out where Apple is storing these parameters. Anybody know?

Here's where I've looked so far:

- I looked at another machine, and confirmed they are not stored in `~/Library/Caches/Java/deployment.properties` any more.
- I also did a lot of `lsof` kind of searching on the new and old machines, but could not find any clues that way, either.
- I searched the old machine (where the 1.7 upgrade never happened) using grep and find and also came up empty, although this search was not exhaustive.

Comment: Why not just set the memory requirement in the JNLP?

Comment: Do you have a link to the regression report?

Comment: The memory requirements vary by user, and this is an old system that is a pain in the butt to update. But yes, I guess JNLP memory setting is probably what I'll have to do if I cannot get an answer.

Comment: I don't have a bug report number yet, but the internal id is 2366943. Here is the question on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074496/any-workaround-to-getting-copy-paste-working-in-jdk-7-awt-applet-on-mac